# Read SDE Feature Attributes without Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, python, enterprise-geodatabase

I've been building some software that reads/writes spatial and non-spatial data out of our SQL SDEs dynamically when called. As I've pointed out before **[Time Delay in Importing ArcPy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194207/time-delay-in-importing-arcpy)** , ArcPy takes forever to import. This has become an issue with my users as the querying and writing tools are too slow for their day to day use.

I am reading and writing data to tables and spatial features within the SDEs using ArcPy cursors (search, update). I've found that cursors work best for the reading and writing of data within SDEs, but I am hoping there is a quicker way without ArcPy.

Comment: arcpy is only slow to import the first time. It's unclear as to why you would need to do this multiple times in a single app. Your data is in SQL Server, not SDE (which no longer exists). There are many ways to access data in a database that don't involve ArcPy, but they all have costs as well as benefits.

Comment: @Vince The app is web based and builds a web page based on a query. Arcpy is called for each query, it's not running at all times in the background. Importing arcpy adds a solid 3-10 seconds for the query.

Comment: That's an application architecture failure. The app ***should*** be running in the background at all times, though doing this without an ArcGIS Server seat is probably a violation of the Desktop license terms.

Comment: @Vince Hmm, I like your idea. My web app is mostly static. User logs in / views datasets / selects dataset / performs query. At the query step is the only time ArcPy is called (that and if they update data). It may be a good idea to have an app running server side, with ArcPy loaded waiting for the queries and updates. Hadn't really considered this as obvious as it seems. Thanks for the input. We do have ArcGIS server, so no licensing issues.

Comment: @CodyBrown That app running server side would be ArcGIS Server ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on which ArcGIS software you have installed you have different options:

- ArcMap: Use ArcObjects. It will cost some time to initialize a license, but maybe you could do that one time
- ArcGIS Server: I *think* ArcObjects is included in Server too, but I never checked.
- ArcGIS Server: If your data is exposed through a FeatureService, you could use ArcGIS Server's REST endpoint for database updates. Either through one of the available clients (See https://developers.arcgis.com/) or by writing raw JSON requests
- ArcGIS Pro: Use the ArcGIS Pro SDK. I have only used this to write Pro addins myself, but it seems to be possible: https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk-community-samples/tree/master/CoreHost/CoreHostResolveAssembly

A different approach would be to use SQL directly. I wouldn't recommend it for complex database operations, but simple insert/update/delete should work. The most important thing to remember is to use the `sde.next_rowid` stored procedure to generate an Object ID for new records. Do *not* try to generate one by calling `MAX(ObjectID) + 1` or something similar. Updating the geometry field depends on the exact type of that field (ST_Geometry, SDE_Geometry, ...)

Comment: ArcObjects sadly is not an option, ArcServer is though I am shall try it. I've never heard of the Pro SDK though, that is an interesting option.

Comment: I forgot about the ArcGIS Server REST endpoint, will update shortly